# Passing varargs to another method as different type

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, variadic-functions

I refactored one of my classes. It should be made serializable. It has a method foo with a parameter of type object varargs.

It may look like:

```
public class MyClass { 
  public void foo(Object ... param) {
    // do sth
  }
}
```

And after the refactoring:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable { 
  public void foo(Serializable ... param) {
    // do sth
  }
}
```

Now, there is another method calling foo and passing its object varargs.

```
public void bar(Object ... param) {
  foo(param);
}
```

At this point, I expected to get an error for passing an Object[] to Serializable[]. In fact, if it would be arrays over varargs, I would.

But instead it will wrap the object varargs into a serializable array.
foo receives a serializable array with 1 element, that is an object array with the passed varargs.

Why is this happening? 
How can I force this wrong usage to actually throw an error at compile-time?

(I am using eclipse neon with Java 1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Serializable...` will take any number of arguments as long as they're all serializable.

Arrays are serializable.

So, it's not going to raise compiler errors (note that because Java is statically typed, it won't be a runtime error).

What you can do is check in `foo` what the argument is, and if `param.length == 1 && param[0] instanceof Object[]` then throw an error. That's probably the best you can do.

Comment: I think its something different, foo is called with one Object of class Object[], and Arrays are Serializable, so no harm done...

Comment: But it would throw a compile-time error if using arrays over varargs. An object array is NOT of the expected type serializable array. The object varargs get auto-wrapped into a serializable array to match the expected type.

Comment: @Gartenzwerg Yes, but do note that `...` is different from `[]`. `[]` requires it to be an array, `...` allows you to pass any number of arguments in the function like `f(a, b, c, ..., z)`

Comment: If foo and bar both expect Serializable varargs. Then bar will pass its varargs in such a way that foo still receives a "flat" serializable array. If the methods expect different types, then bars varargs get autowrapped. I don't get why the latter is happening. Or is the former the feature?

Comment: `Object ...` is effectively an alternative way of writing `Object[]`, and `Object[]` is a subtype of `Serializable`.  Therefore, even though the `Object ...` structure can't be passed element-wise as your `Serializable ...` varargs parameter, the entire `Object ...` structure can get passed as the first element of your `Serializable ...` parameter.

Comment: If Object itself is not Serializable, how would an array of (unserializable) Objects become Serializable? Sooner or later this may cause runtime errors, won't it? Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @Gartenzwerg Actually, that is a good question. You might even want to ask that as a separate question; I'd be interested in knowing too!

Comment: Here you go: [Why do all arrays in java implement serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132936/why-do-all-arrays-in-java-implement-serializable)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing the parameter type from varargs to array:

```
public void foo(Serializable[] param) { }

// called like this
foo(new Serializable[] { param1, param2, param3 } );

// or this
public void bar(Serializable[] param) {
  foo(param);
}
```

This way I regain the type safety at compile time without additional overhead for checking that the varargs parameter is serializable.

Although the manual wrapping of the serializable array adds some noise to the code, this seems to be the best compromise for my case.